# How to sum points calculated in a loop?

Tags: java

I need to sum the points after each round. When I do it it doesn't work. It just outputs the point system under the if statements. Help and an explanation would be very helpful! Thank you from an intro Java coder.

```
public class J1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
       // create random object
       java.util.Random rand = new java.util.Random();
       java.util.Scanner scanner = new java.util.Scanner(System.in); 

        // check next int value  
        System.out.println("Wall height: " + rand.nextInt(10));
        double height = rand.nextInt(10);

        System.out.println("Distance from wall: " + rand.nextInt(20));
            double dist = rand.nextInt(20);

        for(int i = 1; i > 0; i++) {

            System.out.println("Set a lanuch angle between 0 and 90: ");
                double angle = scanner.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Set a lanuch speed: ");
                double speed = scanner.nextDouble();

            double point;
            double a;
            double b;
            double c;
            double d;
            //double e;
            double y;
            a = dist*(Math.tan(Math.toRadians(angle))); 
            b = 9.81*(dist*dist); 
            c = (speed * Math.cos(angle)) * (speed * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle)));
            d = 2*c;
            y = a - (b/d);
            System.out.println("Your max height is " +y+ " high");

            double space;
            space = height - y;

            if(space <= 3 && space > 0) {
                System.out.println("You just made it! ");
                point = 0 - 1 + 3;
                System.out.println("You have " +point+ " points.");
            }

            if (space > 3 && space <= 6) {
                System.out.println("Aww. Plenty of room!");
                point = 0 - 1 + 5;
                System.out.println("You have " +point+ " points.");
            }

            if(space <= 0 && space >= -3) {
                System.out.println("So close!");
                point = 0 - 1 - 2; 
                System.out.println("You have " +point+ " points.");
            }

            if (space < -3) {
                System.out.println("Terrible aim!");
                point = 0 - 1 - 4;
                System.out.println("You have " +point+ " points.");
            }
        }    

        System.out.println("Your total points: " +point);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you want to declare `point` before your `for` loop begins, rather than inside the `for` loop, so that you don't get a new variable each time.  Then each time you assign to `point`, try using `+=` instead of `=`, so that you increase the value of `point` rather than reassigning it.

Answer (score 2):

The declaration of the `point` variable would need to occur outside of the `for` loop for it to be accessible for printing at the end of the code.

It also appears the `for(int i = 1; i > 0; i++) { ... }` loop will run indefinitely, which means the `System.out.println("Your total points: " +point);` line at the end will never be reached. You would need to fix the `for` loop so it only runs a limited amount of times.

The points after each round are never added to the grand total in the `if` sections, you would need to change the statement so that `point +=` instead of `point =`.

I have added a few comments in the code below so you can see which changes have been made. I have also closed the scanner at the end as it is common practice, and fixed the code indentation for clarity purposes:

```
public class J1
{
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
       // create random object
       java.util.Random rand = new java.util.Random();
       java.util.Scanner scanner = new java.util.Scanner(System.in); 

       // check next int value  
       System.out.println("Wall height: " + rand.nextInt(10));
       double height = rand.nextInt(10);

       System.out.println("Distance from wall: " + rand.nextInt(20));
       double dist = rand.nextInt(20);

       double point = 0; //ADD THIS LINE
       for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++) //CHANGED SO THAT i < 10 INSTEAD OF i > 0
       {
           System.out.println("Set a lanuch angle between 0 and 90: ");
           double angle = scanner.nextDouble();
           System.out.println("Set a lanuch speed: ");
           double speed = scanner.nextDouble();

           //double point; *** REMOVE THIS LINE ***
           double a;
           double b;
           double c;
           double d;
           //double e;
           double y;
           a = dist*(Math.tan(Math.toRadians(angle))); 
           b = 9.81*(dist*dist); 
           c = (speed * Math.cos(angle)) * (speed * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle)));
           d = 2*c;
           y = a - (b/d);
           System.out.println("Your max height is " +y+ " high");

           double space;
           space = height - y;

           if(space <= 3 && space > 0)
           {
               System.out.println("You just made it! ");
               point += 0 - 1 + 3; //ADDED += INSTEAD OF =
               System.out.println("You have " +point+ " points.");
           }

           if(space > 3 && space <= 6)
           {
               System.out.println("Aww. Plenty of room!");
               point += 0 - 1 + 5; //ADDED += INSTEAD OF =
               System.out.println("You have " +point+ " points.");
           }

           if(space <= 0 && space >= -3)
           {
               System.out.println("So close!");
               point += 0 - 1 - 2; //ADDED += INSTEAD OF =
               System.out.println("You have " +point+ " points.");
           }

           if(space < -3)
           {
               System.out.println("Terrible aim!");
               point += 0 - 1 - 4; //ADDED += INSTEAD OF =
               System.out.println("You have " +point+ " points.");
           }
        }  
        System.out.println("Your total points: " +point);
        scanner.close(); //ADD THIS LINE
    }
}
```